# Stack Overflow attribution requirements

Tags: discussion, api

We are implementing an app that searches Stack Overflow content. When search results are rendered, we will make sure all the sources and authors are attributed with proper links (clickable) to the source.

But when users have not yet clicked in the search, no reference of Stack Overflow is present.

Is this behavior complying with the Stack Exchange Terms of Services? The https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#attribution is a bit vague when mentioning about data being searched by a search engine.

Comment: Question for Meta Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Exchange, not for the main site.

Comment: Cross-site-dupe of [your own question on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248434/stack-exchange-api-licensing-compliance)

Comment: Just do what google does as far as displaying the content goes and you should be fine. IANAL